# Automatically create setters and getters

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I've read that getters are automatically created when you make a variable public. Can other contracts access these getters or is it only for web3.eth? Also what would be the getter name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The getter's name is the variable's name. So in

```
contract foo {
    int public bar;
}
```

You can access it through `someFooInstance.bar()`. It should work the same in both web3.js and solidity (from another contract.) If it's an array (i.e. `int[] public bar`) or a mapping (`mapping (address=>int) public bar`) you can access specific elements through `someFooInstance.bar(n)`.

There's no way to automatically create a setter, because a setter anyone can access is probably a bad idea. But there's no obvious way to decide who can and can't access a setter.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Do you know how a struct would be accessed?

Comment: Same way. `someStruct public bar`. You'll get an array of _most_ elements. Some, such as arrays within arrays, recursive structs, and mapping won't be returned if they're inside a struct.

Comment: Ok so they're not always so useful it seems. Thanks!